# Java 8 Date time for calculating age in decimals

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I am new in using Java 8 date time API and was wondering how can i able to calculate the age in decimals which returns the double value like 30.5 which means 30 years and 6 months? For example the below sample code gets me the output as 30.0 but not 30.5 which probably am trying for.

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(1984, Month.AUGUST, 10);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.JANUARY, 10);

double numberOfYears = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(startDate, endDate);

System.out.println(numberOfYears); //Getting output as 30.0 but not 30.5
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the Javadoc for `LocalDate` and maybe write some test cases?

Comment: I just posted my sample code up which i was trying to make it work

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes have read the javadoc for LocalDate but have not found any useful information relation to my issue.

Comment: By the way, using decimals in this fashion for date-time handling proves awkward and impractical. Check out the [standard ISO 8601 formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) for representing spans of time as text. The standard formats are supported by default in the java.time classes when parsing/generating strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) for `ChronoUnit`'s `between` method clearly states:

> The calculation returns a whole number, representing the number of complete units between the two temporals.

So you *can't* get 30.5 by just querying for years between. It only will give you the whole number -- 30.

But what you can do is get the months and divide by 12. For greater precision, you could instead use days, or even smaller units.

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(1984, Month.AUGUST, 10);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.JANUARY, 10);

double numberOfMonths = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(startDate, endDate) / 12.0;
System.out.println(numberOfMonths); // prints 30.416666666666668
```

(If your `endDate` was *February* 10, 2015, then it prints 30.5....)

Comment: Oops you are right I should have read that carefully in javadocs as it returns the whole number but not the decimal. Thank you so much for your quick help as your proposed solution works!!!